# A question about two theories and their models

Tags: logic

Suppose $T_1$ and $T_2$ are two theories in the same language and that every model of $T_1$ is a model of $T_2$. I want to show that $T_2$ is contained in $T_1$, but although I think it is clear I can't prove it.
Would be grateful for your help and advices.

Comment: Thanks, but could you specify more or give a reference for me to look for the proof ?

Comment: This depends on how you define "theory" and unfortunately, there are two definitions in common use. Many authors use theory to mean any set of sentences. For these authors, your result is false: e.g., for them, $\{\exists x\forall y\cdot x = y\}$ and $\{\forall x \forall y\cdot x = y\}$ are two different theories with exactly the same class of models. Other authors require theories to be deductively closed:  for them, your result is true as discussed in the answer by James below.

Comment: Thanks very much. Your example was really clarifying.

Comment: Could you please say what is the definitiin for two theories to be equal? Is it to be each contained in the another one or is to have the same models?

Comment: Unless you are working from a text that says otherwise (and I don't know of any such texts), theories are sets of sentences and equality is equality of sets. Do you have an explicit example in mind that makes you think a different definition applies?

Comment: In David Marker's book he wants to show $F_{\forall}$  is the theory of integral domains, he is just satisfied with proving, as in another book :Model theory notes by Kevin Buzzard, that these two theories have the same models. But I myself think we have to show $ACF_{\forall} = ID$. The author has already proved that $Mod(ACF_{\forall}) = Mod(ID)$ and also it is easy to show $ID\subseteq ACF_{\forall}$ also ,but I can't show the converse inclusion. Do you think if $Mod(T_{1}) = Mod(T_{2})$ and $T_{1}\subseteq T_{2}$, then we have $T_{2}\subseteq T_{1}$? If yes our problem is solved? or ...

Comment: I have now had a look at the book and how the lemma that is giving you trouble is used. I've updated my answer to your other question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612597/acf-universal-is-the-theory-of-integral-domains accordingly. The converse that you are asking about above isn't true, but it isn't what Marker needs or proves anyway. I am afraid you have been misled by some sloppy writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Mod(T_1)$ and $Mod(T_2)$ denote the class of models for $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively. Our hypothesis can then be expressed as $Mod(T_1)\subseteq Mod(T_2)$.

Let $\phi\in T_2$, then for every $\mathcal{M}\in Mod(T_2)$, we know $\mathcal{M}\models \phi$. Consequently, for every $\mathcal{N}\in Mod(T_1)$ we know $\mathcal{N}\models \phi$.

So then every model of $T_1$ is also a model of $\phi$, so, by the completeness theorem, there is a proof of $\phi$ from $T_1$, and so, with the extra hypothesis than $T_1$ is closed under deduction, we know $\phi\in T_1$ as required.

(Note we don't need that $T_1$ is consistent, which I had erroneously said earlier.)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't know what's being closed under deduction for a theory. Could you please mention

Comment: A set of sentences $T$ is closed under deduction if every logical consequence of $T$ is also a member of $T$.

Comment: A question more: I need to apply it for the theory of integral domains, do you agree that ID (theory of integral domains) is closed under deduction?

Comment: You need to check your definitions, as, "theory" has competing uses. It is certainly false that the obvious axiomatization (e.g. the commutative ring axioms and $(\forall x\forall y)[xy = 0 \rightarrow x = 0 \lor y= 0]$) of integral domains is not deductively closed, however, the collection of sentences true in all integral domains is closed under deduction.

Comment: But I can't find a sentence showing that is true in all integral domains but does not belong to ID.