# ACF universal is the theory of integral domains

Tags: logic, model-theory

When studying David Marker's "Model Theory: An Introduction" book trying to understand the proof of Lemma 3.2.1 which says: $ACF_{\forall}$ is the theory of integral domains, I couldn't understand the last line of the proof which comes as followa: (I copy the whole proof)

> **Proof.**  The axioms for integral domains are universal consequences of $ACF$.
>   If $D$ is an integral domain, then the algebraic closure of the fraction field
>   of $D$ is a model of $ACF$. Because every integral domain is a subring of an
>   algebraically closed field, $ACF_{\forall}$ is the theory of integral domains.

David Marker wants to show $ACF_{\forall}$  is the theory of integral domains, he is just satisfied with proving, as in another book :Model theory notes by Kevin Buzzard(which you can find it in page 12-13 from the link below*), that these two theories have the same models. But I myself think we have to show $ACF_{\forall} = ID$. The author has already proved that $Mod(ACF_{\forall}) = Mod(ID)$ and it is easy to show $ID\subseteq ACF_{\forall}$ also ,but I can't show the converse inclusion. Do you think if $Mod(T_{1}) = Mod(T_{2})$ and $T_{1}\subseteq T_{2}$, then we have $T_{2}\subseteq T_{1}$ for two theories $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$? If yes our problem is solved? or ...

I also asked this question in this manner which couldn't lead me to my very mean if you want to see:
"[A question about two theories and their models](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610752/a-question-about-two-theories-and-their-models)  "

Please say if my understanding of the original proof is true or not? and help to prove it, please.

*http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/notes/model_theory_notes.pdf

Comment: When you say it is easy to prove that $ID \subseteq ACF_{|forall}$, I suspect you are thinking of $ID$ as the usual finite axiomatisation of integral domains. If that is the case then the converse inclusion does not hold, but as per my answer below, this isn't what Marker needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the phrase "is the theory of integral domains" in the statement and proof of Marker's Lemma 3.2.1 is very sloppy. What Marker actually means is that $ACF_{\forall}$ axiomatizes the class of integral domains and that is what the proof proves (and is what is needed at the point of use of the lemma to show that $ACF$ has algebraically prime models).

It is clearly wrong to say that $ACF_{\forall}$ is the (full) theory of integral domains (which is the only notion of theory of a class of structures that Marker has defined), as there are sentences like $\forall x \exists y\cdot x + y = 0$ that hold in any integral domain but are not purely universal.

The closest you can get to a true statement along the lines of Marker's actual statement of the lemma is that $ACF_{\forall} = ID_{\forall}$, but that isn't exactly what is wanted where the lemma is used.

Comment: Dear Rob Arthan, I found your clarification very helpful. But again I have a problem maybe you could help. In the first line of the proof which says  "The axioms for integral domains are universal consequences of  ACF." Now doesn't it contradict with existence of the sentence "for all element there is an element which their sum is zero", as you mentioned? Now I think we have to prove $Mod(ACF_{\forall})=Mod(ID)$-at least we have to show every model of $ACF_{\forall}$ is an integral domain-to be able to say that ACF has algebraic prime models; but I can't show it and I don't see it in the book.

Comment: By including (unary) negation, or (binary) subtraction (as Marker does) in the language for rings, you don't need an existential quantifier to express the existence of additive inverses. See the axiomatiization in Marker's example 1.2.8.: from the existence of multiplicative inverses (the last axiom), you can deduce that in a field, $\forall x\forall y(xy = 0 \implies x = 0 \lor y = 0)$, which is a universal sentence that together with the (universal sentences that form the axioms of rings) axiomatizes integral domains. That's the detailed reasoning behind the first sentence of the proof.

Comment: If you are having difficulty understanding Marker's axioms for rings and fields, then I think you should ask a new question about that. (Marker's formulation is a bit unusual in taking binary subtraction rather than unary negation as a primitive.)

Comment: Dear Mr. Rob, thank you very much.  Adding "-" as a binary function to the language of rings and the sentence $\forall x(x+(-x)=0)$ to the set of axioms solves our problem, but I can't see how Professor Marker's way adding the second axiom-$\forall x \forall y \forall z(x-y=z \longleftrightarrow x=y+z)$- is really proving the existence of the additive inverse! and he also says including − in the language will useful later; and I don't see how? Is it by deducing from the second axiom that: $\forall x (x-x=0 \longleftrightarrow x=x+0=x)$ is it right to say so, can we change the axiom in this way

Comment: Using Marker's signature for a ring, the additive inverse is given by the function $x \mapsto 0 - x$. As I said, if you are having difficulties with Marker's axiomatization, then I think it would better for you to ask a new question.

Comment: The axiom $0\neq 1$ is in the axioms for integral domains; could we say it is universal by rewriting it as $\forall x(x=x \wedge \neg0=1)$?

Comment: You are right that integral domains require $0 \neq 1$, bi  quantifier-free counts as purely universal, so $0 \neq 1$ will do as it stands.